# Editing "nonexistent" answer resulting in test shows "Answer didn't exist" message

Tags: discussion, support

I was reviewing the First Posts queue, when I hit [this test](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/432818). I usually edit answers/questions with explicit links and embed them to some relevant term (like "This tool...", "This answer...", etc.), so I clicked on `Edit`, besides of trying to make it salvageable.

A page saying that this answer didn't exist showed up (don't have the exact text, though), so I supposed meantime someone deleted it and went back. Therefore, I was about to click on the `No Action Needed` button... and I would have failed that test. I had a feeling about that so I tried to downvote it and I finally passed the test.

The question is: Shouldn't the `Edit` button make the reviewer pass that test instead of showing the "Nonexistent answer" message?

Comment: One tip:  you can always use the available links to go from any review item , to the whole Q&A and see everything.  I find that is sometimes the only way to see what really is going on, i find that to be a pain in the butt too :-) , but it is one sure way to see everything before judging anything.

Comment: Yep, I do that too when in doubt - There are some questions that need to be seen completely before doing anything. I just asked to see opinions about turning the `Edit` button into a "Test passed" greeting :-P

Comment: The same thing happens with comments.  You spend time finding the canonical links and writing advice in a comment, only to have the comment rejected because the post no longer exists.  The flip side is that if just clicking Edit or Comment was enough to satisfy the audit, people would just click and cancel one of those immediately to pass a potential audit without thinking about the post, which would sort of defeat the purpose.

Comment: I understand that, but in this case the effect would be exactly the same, because right now someone could simply click on `Edit` and wait for the "nonexistent answer" to show up to know it is an audit and then downvote. Additionally, this is not always this way, because you shouldn't edit a good answer or question, IMHO in this case the audit should be considered failed.

Comment: @Psycogeek, I agree and although it seems like cheating, it's better than getting locked out for a month... my current situation.  Which happened when the same question popped up again.  I got it right the first time.  The second time I got confused and was trying to skip it but pressed the wrong button - and I am in the sin-bin for  a month.  Just have to laugh at it.